# Слайдер с изображением в 100vh и областью видимости в 400px

Tags: javascript, css, слайдер

Кто подскажет как реализовать такой эффект.
Есть слайдер. он где то в середине страницы условно. Необходимо чтобы изображение было растянуто на 100vh, но область видимости была допустим 400px.
Поясню для чего. При скролле страницы автопролистывание слайдера будет останавливаться, изображение фиксированное у нас будет становиться и получится эффект, что в области видимости при скролле будет постепенно показываться все изображение. Вот тут в третьем блоке, только вместо статичного изображения будет слайдер https://yola-umney.ru/